# How to construct a Django query that filters each element of a list?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to construct a query which takes the currently logged in users  nearestzips which is a list of 5 postal codes, and then filters through all items for sale that match these 5 postal codes.

## models.py

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    streetaddress=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                       max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    nearestzips = models.Charfield(null=True, blank=True, max_length=80)
```

## views.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    zipcode =models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=10)
```

## printing nearestzips from the console

```
print testprofile.nearestzips
>>>[<PostalCode=97202>, <PostalCode=97201>, <PostalCode=97215>, <PostalCode=97239>, <PostalCode=97214>]
```

## And finally, here is the query I am trying to construct.

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode="user.nearestzips")
```

My question is, since nearestzips is a list, how can I filter through the 5 elements of that list?  Can I simply add [0:4] after 'nearestzipcodes' or do I have to do something like this:

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode="user.nearestzips[0]").filter(zipcode="user.nearestzips[1]").filter(zipcode="user.nearestzips[3]"), etc.
```

Any help would be apprecitaed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since nearestzips is a string, you'll need to first parse MyProfile.nearestzips to get a proper list. If you're already doing that somewhere, your query is pretty simple:

```
zip_list = user.nearestzips # Assuming this returns a proper list
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=zip_list)
```

If user.nearestzips isn't returning a list, you can add a custom method to the MyProfile object to return the zip codes in list format:

```
def get_nearestzips(self, *args, **kwargs):
    zip_list = self.nearestzips.replace("PostalCode=","")
    return zip_list.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the __in field lookup in django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in

The syntax is filter(col_name__in=list).  Since your input is a dictionary you have to use the list.values() function to generate the data for your "in" filter input.

So put all together:

```
nearby_entry = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=testprofile.nearestzips.values())
```

**Update Feb13:**
If you nearestzips is a queryset then you have to either convert it to a list or use values_list to get the data instead.

Method1: convert

> zip_list = [z.postalcode for z in testprofile.nearestzips]

Method2: values_list assuming nearestzips is a many2many field

> zip_list = testprofile.nearestzips.values_list('postalcode',
>   flat=True)

Comment: This gives me TypeError: cannot use multifield geovaluesqueryset as a fiilter value.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the issue, but 'nearestzips' was created by this line: nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='user.zipcode').location).order_by('distance')[:9]

Comment: can I use __in with django 1.6?